# Calculating wavelenght of an accelerated electron

Tags: photoelectric-effect

The rest mass of the relativistic electron is $m$, what's the electron's wavelength if it gets accelerated by a potential difference $U$.
Is it right to use dee Broglie equation for wavelength, finding the velocity from the formula $E_\text{kin}=eU$? What mass should I use at de Broglie equation and at the $E_\text{kin}$ equation?

Answer (score 0):

The rest mass $m$ of the electron is 511 keV (with $c = 1$). The connection of energy, mass and momentum is $m^2 = E^2 - p^2$. The de Broglie relation is best stated as $\lambda = 2\pi / p$ (with $\hbar = 1$). The energy of the electron after the acceleration is $E = m + eU$.

Now you just have to solve the equations such that you get the wavelength $\lambda$:

> $$\displaystyle \lambda= \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{E^2 - m^2}} = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{(m + eU)^2 - m^2}}= \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{2 meU + (eU)^2}} \,.$$

With all the factors of $c$ and $\hbar$, it will become

> $$\displaystyle \lambda= \frac{2\pi c \hbar}{\sqrt{2 m c^2 eU + (eU)^2}} \,.$$

Comment: This was a question in a physics competition.

Comment: The problem didnt give any value for the potential.

Comment: It just said that it is a relativistic electron